# How do I deploy a Hardsuit?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

I've attempted to deploy a Hardsuit that I bought, but the circle around the hologram just flashes red/blue/green. Googling did not help me at all with any of this.

How do you deploy a Hardsuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardsuits need a clear view of the sky to come down (im uncertain if this rule applies in indoor maps, though). once the hologram is BLUE you can start calling it down. click and hold while aiming where the blue hologram appears. It will take about 2 seconds for it to charge and call it down.

source:

Comment: The relevant part of the video starts at about 5:05